# How can I pass instance attributes as arguments automatically when running a function stored as an instance attribute?

Tags: python, oop

I am building out a class `A` to ultimately perform a particular statistical operation. I can set both a function and the arguments for that function as instance attributes, using class methods I have written. I would then like to be able to run the function, with the arguments being sourced from the instance attributes automatically. It is unclear to me if there is nimble way to do this as I am conceiving it or if another implementation is necessary.

A toy version of the relevant code so far, with `run_function` stopping short of what I ultimately want it to do:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,2.,"a"],[0,8.,"q"],[1,3.5,"a"],[1,9.5,"g"]],
    columns=["binary","float","letters"]
    )

c = "binary"
v = 1

def test_fn(df,c:str,v:list):
    if not isinstance(v,list):
        v = [v]

    return (df[c].isin(v)).sum()


class A():
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df

    def _set_fn_args(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def set_function(self,function,**kwargs):
        self.fn = function
        self._set_fn_args(**kwargs)

    def run_function(self,df=None,**kwargs):
        if df is None:
            df = self.df
        return self.fn(df,**kwargs)

a = A(df)
a.set_function(test_fn,c=c,v=v)

a.__dict__.keys()
# dict_keys(['df', 'fn', 'c', 'v'])

a.fn
# <function __main__.test_fn(df, c: str, v: list)>

a.run_function(c=a.c,v=a.v) 
# 3
```

The method `set_function` stores any input function as a class attribute `fn`, so that the statistical operation can be run over any function. `**kwargs` can be passed to the function, that through the child method `_set_fn_arguments` stores these variables as class attributes. Another function, `run_function`, runs the function stored as `fn`.

Currently, I have to write in each argument for `run_function`, which pretty much defeats the purpose of storing these as class attributes. I would also like to be able to source the function arguments from `A` according to their names. In this example, I'd like to write `run_function` such that `run_function()` will source all necessary arguments (`c` and `v`) from within `a` when `self.c` and `self.v` are defined.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Is there another way you would write the class to accomplish the same outcome?

Comment: You appear to be trying to reimplement `functools.partial`: `f = partial(test_function, df); f(c="...", v=[1,2,3])` is the same as `test_function(df, c="...", v=[1,2,3])`.

Comment: @chepner thanks! could you demonstrate how you would use `functools.partial` to solve the problem of automatically accessing these attributes from within an instance?

Comment: I'm saying I don't see why you need `A` at all. Creating the `partial` instance takes the place of `set_function`, and calling the `partial` takes the place of `run_function`.

Comment: @chepner there a statistical function from in the actual implementation of `A`  that I did not include in the toy code because it's not relevant to this issue beyond being the reason for `A` existing in the first place.